# In scikit-learn, check_estimator for ClassifierMixin

Tags: python, testing, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a "Scikit-Learn compliant" classifier by extending BaseEstimator and ClassifierMixin. I have read the [documentation on their website](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#apis-of-scikit-learn-objects) and I also tried to follow some guides online like [this one](http://danielhnyk.cz/creating-your-own-estimator-scikit-learn/)

I can create estimators that pass the `check_estimator()` test. However, whenever I try to create a classifier, it never passes the test. Even the [template](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/project-template/_modules/skltemplate/template.html#TemplateClassifier) that Scikit-Learn provides doesn't pass the test...

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_X_y, check_is_fitted, check_array
from sklearn.utils.estimator_checks import check_classifiers_classes
from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances
import numpy as np

class MyCustomClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, param1=2):
        self.param1 = param1

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        # Check that X and y have correct shape
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y)

        # Store the classes seen during fit
        self.classes_ = np.unique(y)

        self.X_ = X
        self.y_ = y

        return self


    def predict(self, X):
        # Check is fit had been called
        check_is_fitted(self, ['X_', 'y_', 'classes_'])

        # Input validation
        X = check_array(X)

        closest = np.argmin(euclidean_distances(X, self.X_), axis=1)

        return self.y_[closest]

MyCustomClassifier()

from sklearn.utils.estimator_checks import check_estimator

check_estimator(MyCustomClassifier)
```

It seems that I am forgetting some type of test that would raise an error because this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vca/Google Drive/Internship/Skratch/supervised/logistic_regression.py", line 97, in <module>
    check_estimator(MyCustomClassifier)
  File "C:\Users\vca\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\skratch\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\estimator_checks.py", line 265, in check_estimator
    check(name, estimator)
  File "C:\Users\vca\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\skratch\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\testing.py", line 291, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vca\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\skratch\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\estimator_checks.py", line 1729, in check_classifiers_regression_target
    assert_raises_regex(ValueError, msg, e.fit, X, y)
  File "C:\Users\vca\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\skratch\lib\unittest\case.py", line 1258, in assertRaisesRegex
    return context.handle('assertRaisesRegex', args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vca\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\skratch\lib\unittest\case.py", line 176, in handle
    callable_obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vca\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\skratch\lib\unittest\case.py", line 196, in __exit__
    self.obj_name))
  File "C:\Users\vca\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\skratch\lib\unittest\case.py", line 134, in _raiseFailure
    raise self.test_case.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: ValueError not raised by fit
```

Anybody who successfully created a classifier that passes the test?

Comment: ```def check_classifiers_regression_target(name, Estimator):
    # Check if classifier throws an exception when fed regression targets
```
that is the function that throws the error ... Not sure how to detect this "when fed regression targets".

Comment: I actually literally just found out how to fix this. By indeed running the test that checks that

Answer (score 3):

I just found out how to fix this. One needs to run `check_classification_targets` in the fit. This apparently raises an error if regression targets are used.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import check_classification_targets
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_X_y, check_is_fitted, check_array

class MyCustomClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, param1=2):
        self.param1 = param1

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):
        # Check that X and y have correct shape
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
        check_classification_targets(y)

        # Store the classes seen during fit
        self.classes_ = np.unique(y)

        self.X_ = X
        self.y_ = y

        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        # Check is fit had been called
        check_is_fitted(self, ['X_', 'y_', 'classes_'])

        # Input validation
        X = check_array(X)

        closest = np.argmin(euclidean_distances(X, self.X_), axis=1)

        return self.y_[closest]
```

Comment: No need for that extra `check_array(X)`. It will be done in the `check_X_y()`

Comment: Indeed, it will be done in check_X_y(), and the test will run without it. But what if I use predict with new data, and that data doesn't work well with the format. As in, what if I don't use predict on known test data for instance. Wouldn't it be safer to keep the extra check_array()?

Comment: Yes. For predict() its ok. I was talking about fit(). Sorry if misundertood. I commented that check_X_y will handle that and that is only done in fit(). So I assumed that its clear that I am talking about fit().

Comment: Oh my bad, I will edit my post. I somehow forgot to delete it. Thanks for your feedback!